# Show images from dynamically created path

Tags: php, mysql, image

I saved multiple images into dynamically created database path. But now the problem is that images are not showing while fetching.I have added my two tables in database and also php code and directory that I created when entering images. I think my problem is image source. I am unable to modify the image source path. Plz help.

I have two tables in database: 1st Table: `advt`

```
- ad_id
- cus_id
- ad_name
- ad_des
- date
```

2nd table : `Full texts`

```
- img_id
- ad_name
- img_name (type: longblob)
- img_type
- img_size
```

This is my php code to show images from database path:

```
<?php 
include('include/config.php');

 if($stmt2 = $connection->prepare("SELECT img_id, ad_name, img_name, img_type, img_size FROM `full texts`")){ 

       $stmt2->execute(); 
       $stmt2->store_result(); 
       $stmt2->bind_result($img_id, $ad_name, $img_name, $img_type, $img_size); 
       while($stmt2->fetch()){ 
         ?>
           <img src="'ad/data/img/'.$cus_id.'/'.$ad_id.'/'<?php echo $img_name; ?>" width="220" height="220"><br>

         <?php
       } 
       $stmt2->close();
    } 
?>
```

This is below how I created directory to save images:

```
$cus_id = $_POST['cus_id'];
$ad_id = $_POST['ad_id'];
$dir='ad/data/img/'.$cus_id.'/'.$ad_id.'/';
if(!file_exists($dir) || !is_dir($dir)){
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    chmod($dir, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: why you are storing img_name as blob? You can simply use varchar and save the image name there like "abc.jpg" and refer that here 

(
<img src="'ad/data/img/'.$cus_id.'/'.$ad_id.'/'<?php echo $img_name; ?>" width="220" height="220"><br>)

Comment: @Bikesh M Annur I changed img_name as varchar according to your suggestion. But till now images are not showing.

Comment: I would suggest you to verify if there is any adblockers installed, and test again by turning them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    include('include/config.php');

    if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
                                     a.img_id, 
                                     a.ad_name, 
                                     a.img_name, 
                                     a.img_type, 
                                     a.img_size, 
                                     b.ad_id, 
                                     b.cus_id 
                                     FROM `full texts` a 
                                     INNER JOIN advt b
                                     ON a.ad_name=b.ad_name
                                     ")){ 


           $stmt->execute(); 
           $stmt->store_result(); 
           $stmt->bind_result($img_id, $ad_name, $img_name, $img_type, $img_size, $ad_id, $cus_id);   

           while($stmt->fetch()){ 

              echo  "<img src=ad/data/img/$cus_id/$ad_id/$img_name  width='220' height='220'><br>";


           } 
           $stmt->close();
           } 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think error is in your php code because of using php variable outside `<?PHP?>`

**corrected code:**

```
    <?php 
include('include/config.php');

 if($stmt2 = $connection->prepare("SELECT img_id, ad_name, img_name, img_type, img_size FROM `full texts`")){ 

       $stmt2->execute(); 
       $stmt2->store_result(); 
       $stmt2->bind_result($img_id, $ad_name, $img_name, $img_type, $img_size); 
       while($stmt2->fetch()){ 

          echo  "<img src=ad/data/img/$cus_id/$ad_id/$img_name  width="220" height='220'><br>";


       } 
       $stmt2->close();
    } 
?>
```

**addition**

```
$stmt3 = $connection->prepare("SELECT ad_id, cus_id, ad_name, ad_des, date FROM `advt`" //where condition to particular img_id)
       $stmt3->execute(); 
           $stmt3->store_result(); 
           $stmt3->bind_result($ad_id, $cus_id, $ad_name, $ad_des, $date);
```

Comment: The problem is now: Notice: Undefined variable: cus_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\nfs\imageShow.php on line 10 Notice: Undefined variable: ad_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\nfs\imageShow.php on line 10

Comment: its because you didnt fetch from `1st table ` ad_id&cus_if are from table one you are fetching only from table 2

Comment: How will I connect 1st table with 2nd table here with prepared statement plz guide.

Comment: use where condition in both select statements and fetch records .i didnt update because i dont have full code

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you've pasted what your browser got, html code.
But you're mixing php and plain html a bit and lost in it, it should rather be:
           `echo '<img src="ad/data/img/'.$cus_id.'/'.$ad_id.'/'.$img_name.'" width="220" height="220"><br>';`

No `?>` before that block and no `<?php` after.

Comment: I want to simply fetch images from database. There is no past pages now. That is why I added directory when uploading images. The problem is now: Notice: Undefined variable: cus_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\nfs\imageShow.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: ad_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\nfs\imageShow.php on line 10

Comment: PHP is right - what is stored in cus_id? You're not getting it from the database. You're only taking $img_id, $ad_name, $img_name, $img_type, $img_size, but not $cus_id, which you're using when building the path.

Comment: `ad_id, cus_id` both comes from the 1st table `advt`.  cus_id is customer id

Comment: Yes, but you're not selecting it - these are not in the SELECT, so PHP could not initialize the variable with the value - it's initialized when you used it to create the path, but it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($stmt2->fetch()){ 

    $src = 'ad/data/img/'.$cus_id.'/'.$ad_id.'/'.$img_name;
     ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" width="220" height="220"><br>

     <?php
   }
```

Comment: The problem is now: Notice: Undefined variable: cus_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\nfs\imageShow.php on line 10   Notice: Undefined variable: ad_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\root\nfs\imageShow.php on line 10